# script can run in uppercase and lowercase both in switch function java script

Tags: javascript, html

As we know, there are those people who don't properly capitalize words, those who type in all caps, and then there are those who don't ever bother with capitalization.

I wonder how to make the code run even if the person doesn't enter the exact string I put in each switch()

```
  <html>
<body>
<script>
var days='thu'; 
 switch(days)
            {
               case 'Mon':
                document.write("Today is Monday");
                break;
               case 'Tue':
                document.write("Today is Tuesday");
                break;
               case 'Wed':
                document.write("Today is Wednesday");
                break;
               case 'Thu':
                document.write("Today is Thursday");
                break;
               case 'Fri':
                document.write("Today is Friday");
                break;
               default:
               document.write("Weekend...!!!");
            }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to use `toLowerCase()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before comparing convert the input to lowercase or uppercase. Then have to cases in lowercase or uppercase.

Something like

```
 switch(days.toLowerCase())
            {
               case 'mon':
                document.write("Today is Monday");
                break;
               case 'tue':
                document.write("Today is Tuesday");
```

So the code works for both the cases.

```
var days='thu'; //or  var days='Thu';
 switch(days.toLowerCase())
```

If you do not want to touch days at all, the below way works. But I dont personally prefer it

```
case 'Mon':
case 'mon':      
document.write("Today is Monday");
break;
case 'Ton':
case 'tue':      
document.write("Today is Tuesday");
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can covert it to lowercase then check.

```
switch(days.toLowerCase())
{
   case 'mon':
       document.write("Today is Monday");
       break;
   case 'tue':
       document.write("Today is Tuesday");
       break;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder how to make the code run even if the person doesn't enter the
>   exact string I put in each switch()

You can take first three characters of `days` and convert the result to **title-case**

```
days = days.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + days.substring( 0,2 ); //put this line before `switch`
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to convert it into uppercase or lowercase then you can match it

example for if you used uppercase

```
switch(days.toUpperCase())
   case 'MON':
                document.write("Today is Monday");
                break;
               case 'TUE':
                document.write("Today is Tuesday");
                break;
               case 'WED':
                document.write("Today is Wednesday");
                break;
               case 'THU':
                document.write("Today is Thursday");
                break;
               case 'FRI':
                document.write("Today is Friday");
                break;
               default:
               document.write("Weekend...!!!");
```

Or you can do it asa well as in lowercase

```
switch(days.toLowerCase())
   case 'mon':
                document.write("Today is Monday");
                break;
               case 'tue':
                document.write("Today is Tuesday");
                break;
               case 'wed':
                document.write("Today is Wednesday");
                break;
               case 'thu':
                document.write("Today is Thursday");
                break;
               case 'fri':
                document.write("Today is Friday");
                break;
               default:
               document.write("Weekend...!!!");
```

Answer (score -1):

years ago i would think to .toLowerCase() or any other javascript or framework's function too. BUT making a little step back and see entirely picture you should ask yourself: "from where i grab some feedback ? a string without proper capitalization? is not from input directly?  "

the answer is a new question : isn't from a input perhaps?

```html
<form method="post" action="">
The lower text:(try caps lock key to both!)<input type="text" name="" style="text-transform: lowercase;"><br>
 This is caps by default:<input type="text" name="" style="text-transform: uppercase;">
  </form>
```

TRY TO **RUN CODE SNIPPET** BUTTON !
Sometimes you can avoid operations from the origin of the feedback

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does adding a `style`  attribute (which is for pure styling!) resolve the given problem?

Answer (score -3):

How to convert string in lowercase

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>
  <body>

   <h2>Convert string into UpperCase</h2>
   <p id  = "string"></p>

   <script>
    var text1 = "Good Moring";
    var text2 = text1.toLowerCase(); 
    document.getElementById("string").innerHTML = text2;
  
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does your code relate to the given problem?

Comment: my code is use to convert string into lowercase and uppercase .i can define simple way to convert string .

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it